# Powershell Open File and Replace special character + NULL

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm trying to open a csv file which has many special characters like '& @ *' and replace that with '_'. I'd also like to replace all 'NULL' strings to ' '. 
Once that's done, save the file to the same location.

I've tried this

```
$File = Import-Csv "C:\Users\a\Desktop\Al.csv"

foreach ($line in $File)
{
    $line.Replace('[[+*@?()\\.]','_')
    $line.Replace('NULL','')
}
```

EDIT: Thanks to the comments was able to do this with

```
(get-content "C:\Users\a\Desktop\Al.csv") -replace ('[[+*@?()\\]','_') -replace('NULL','') | Set-Content "C:\Users\a\Desktop\Al.csv"
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you add the code where you ran into issues?

Comment: `Import-Csv` doesn't return lines, it returns PSObjects with properties for each CSV column. `$line.Replace(...)` doesn't change a variable in-place, it returns a value which you're not using. `foreach()`  doesn't output to the pipeline so it's a bad choice for this. `(get-content "c:\...\A1.csv" -raw).replace(...).replace(...) | set-content "c:\...\A1.csv"`

Comment: What @TessellatingHeckler said. Also, the `Replace()` method does simple string replacements. For regular expression replacements use the `-replace` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to read the file in as if it were simply a binary block of data, then do your replace of the characters you don't want, then save it back out.

The fact that it is a CSV or even a TXT for what your trying to do makes no difference.

Get-content for example will read everything, and not limit you to the CSV format.